# connection refused when i execute oc new-project demo

Tags: openshift, redhat

Openshift local has been installed successfully I can see that running on mac.
but when i do `oc new-project demo`

The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:63267 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Comment: Did you login successfully?

Comment: The default OCP port is 6443, Can u check if your ocp reachable with: `telnet 127.0.0.1 63267`,

Comment: @DavidOgren yes login is fine.sudo oc login -u kubeadmin -p https://api.crc.testing:6443
Password:
Login successful.

You have access to 68 projects, the list has been suppressed. You can list all projects with 'oc projects'

Using project "default".
error: getwd: invalid argument
but again when i try doing
sudo oc projects
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:63267 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer, but here are some troubleshooting steps based on your comments.

First, you should **not** be executing `oc` with `sudo`. My initial guess is that your problems are related to that mistake: you may have changed some of your configuration files to owned by root and/or corrupted them somehow.

Try `oc config get-contexts`. This will list all of the currently defined clusters. Check to make sure that localhost or 63267 isn't in there anywhere. As selllami points out, 63267 isn't an expected port (nor is localhost a expected host).

Also check the permissions on your kubeconfig files: `ls -l ~/.kube`, especially if you see something unusual in your context in the previous step.

You may find the answer obvious from these steps and be able to resolve the problem by fixing your permissions or your context definition. But, if not, you may just want to delete your `.kube` directory and login again without using `sudo` so that the proper config is created. (Of course, backup the directory first, especially if you have other K8S clusters you connect to.)